# How to prove this recurrence relation with induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

$b_n = 4b_{n-1}-3b_{n-2}, b_1=0, b_2=12$

I solved the recurrence relation and got the following formula:
$b_n = 2 \cdot 3^n-6$

The challenging part is that the $b$ depends on two preceding elements. So, how should I prove that formula with induction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you usually do.  Some people call it strong induction when you assume the solution holds all the way up to $k$ instead of just at $k$, then prove it holds for $k+1$.  You need two base cases, which you have in $b_1,b_2$.  Then assuming it works up to $k$ you have $$ \begin {align}b_{k+1}& =4b_k-3b_{k-1}\\& =4(2\cdot 3^k-6)-3(2\cdot3^{k-1}-6)\\& =24\cdot3^{k-1}-24-6\cdot3^{k-1}+18\\& =2\cdot3^{k+1}-6 \end {align}$$

Comment: Thanks Ross! I just wasn't sure I can set two base cases.